# When I try to write to an NTFS partition in Arch Linux, it fails with "cannot open <file>: permission denied". Why?

Tags: permissions, mount, ntfs

I'm running Arch Linux off a flash drive. `/dev/sdb1` is mounted as `/`, `/dev/sdb2` is mounted as `/home`.

`/dev/sda3` is the main NTFS partition on the internal hard drive of my laptop. I have it mounted, and I'm trying to create a swapfile on it. The intended resullt is that when it's booted from this particular laptop, it'll mount the main partition and start using the swapfile. I'm following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap#Swap_file_creation) on the Arch Wiki.

However, when I try to `fallocate` or `dd`, I get "[fallocate/dd]: failed to open swapfile: permission denied". Why does this happen?

I'm attaching the log below, including `uname -a`, `lsblk`, etc. at the bottom. (Note that I'm in a root shell.)

```
[root@alex-arch /]# mount /mnt/xps13/
[root@alex-arch /]# cd /mnt/xps13/
[root@alex-arch xps13]# fallocate -l 2G swapfile
fallocate: cannot open swapfile: Permission denied
[root@alex-arch xps13]# dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=1G count=2
dd: failed to open ‘swapfile’: Permission denied
[root@alex-arch xps13]# uname -a
Linux alex-arch 3.9.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat May 25 16:14:55 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@alex-arch xps13]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  12.3G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0    99G  0 part /mnt/xps13
└─sda4   8:4    0     8G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1   7.3G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   4.3G  0 part /
└─sdb2   8:18   1     3G  0 part /home
[root@alex-arch xps13]# cat /etc/fstab 
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/sdb1
UUID=3c38780b-7f24-4564-aa9c-ad8a31f226c9   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/sdb2
UUID=4e044617-654f-4eef-a73d-1db9f74e7660   /home       ext4        rw,relatime 0 2

UUID=44AE893EAE89298E                           /mnt/xps13  ntfs            rw,users,nofail,auto    0 0
[root@alex-arch xps13]#
```

Comment: It's not recommended to put swapfiles on a NTFS partition. The kernel `ntfs` driver is incomplete, and the FUSE `ntfs-3g` driver...well, what would happen if ntfs-3g got swapped out?